# Query by value in Hazelcast (SQL like operation)

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to store the below structure in the Hazelcast cache. (Still not finalized the structure)

Value1/unique key
    {

```
    "isin":"isin123",
    "id_bb_global":"BBg12345676",
    "cusip":"cusip123",
    "sedol":"sedol123",
    "cpn":"0.09",
    "cntry":"US",
    "144A":"xyz",
    "issue_cntry":"UK"
}

    Value2/unique key/
    {

    "isin":"isin222",
    "id_bb_global":"BBG222",
    "cusip":"cusip222",
    "sedol":"sedol222",
    "cpn":"1.0",
    "cntry":"IN",
    "144A":"Y",
    "issue_cntry":"DE"
    }
```

...
...
I want to search by cusip or cusip and id_bb_global, ISIN plus Exchange, or sedol.

e.g - search query data -> 
{"isin":"isin222" AND "issue_cntry":"UK"} , should return all data sets from value2.
{"sedol":"sedol123" OR "id_bb_global":"BBg12345676"} should return all data sets from value 1

Question:

1. What is the best way to store this kind of data structure in Hazelcast?
2. How to do SQL like operation and how it's performance? Is Predicate - https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.3-RC1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/query/class-use/Predicate.html is a good choice? The issue is, my object is going to change as and when I add a new attribute(s) - e.g - add new attributes to the existing data structure -  {existing + maturity,ISO,  etc}

PS: I am planning to use Hazelcast in cluster mode using Consul Discovery.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in JSON format in a Hazelcast map and then query JSON directly. See here for more details and example: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.5/manual/html-single/index.html#querying-json-strings